# How to get userId from token?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-jwt

I'm coding a simple get endpoint, and I send from front-end header the token information. But in back-end I need to use userId. I think it is available on token, but how can I get userId from token?

```
// React Front End service
const response = await fetch(
             `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST}/export-data/pdf?${urlParams}`,
             {
                 headers: {
                     ...authService.authHeader(),
                     Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.getToken()}`,
                 },
             }
         );

// Nestjs Back End controller
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    @Permissions('admin')
    @Get('/pdf')
    async exportDataPdf(@Query() query: GetOrdersFilterDto): Promise<any> {
        // I need to use userId from token here.
        return await this.exportDataService.exportDataPdf(query);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you sign `this.jwtService.sign()` while signIn a user / while generating jwt token.

For example if you use

```
this.jwtService.sign({ userId: user._id });
```

Then you can simply do this on your controller

```
@Get('profile')
  getUserId(@Request() req: any) {
    return req.user.userId;
  }
```

Note `req.user` object is used internally by nestjs to store jwt payload data.

In case you want any data you provide on jwt in a nestjs guard. You can also get access it from `req` object.

```
canActivate(
 context: ExecutionContext,
): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
 const [req] = context.getArgs();

 // console log user ID
 console.log(req.user.userId);

 // create your conditional logic here before return true
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method called `getUserIdFromToken` and use it for that. If `bcrypt` was used to create the token out of the email, you can get the email back from it.
Here is how I did it in node:

- Encode the token

```
const hashData = { email: user.email }
const accessToken = jwt.sign(hashData, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

- Decode the token

```
const email = jwtDecode(token).email;
```

Then, you can retrieve the user with the email.

Comment: this answer doesn't show how to get the `token` inside `exportDataPdf`